# How to split a string when an alphanumeric word found in a string using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have below code which finds alphanumeric word in a string then it changes it to uppercase.

Now, I'd like to split the string into two parts String is in cell A1. Cell value is "Free 90x90mm dewsc"

If the first word of the string is an alphanumeric then don't do anything. Paste the value in cell B1.

If string has alphanumeric word then split the string into two columns.

Cell B1 should contain words from start to alphanumeric word. i.e "Free"

Cell  C1 contain words from alphanumeric word to till end of the string. i.e "90x90mm dewsc"

```
Sub Main()
    Dim longString, result As String
    Dim arrayString() As String
    Dim newarr As String
    Dim substr As String

    Set objRegExp_1 = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    objRegExp_1.Pattern = "((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))" 'REGEX for alphanumeric words in the string

    longString = "Free 90x90mm desc"

    arrayString = Split(longString) 'Splits the string into an array of words so that each one can be matched with the REGEX pattern to check if its alphanumeric

    For i = 0 To UBound(arrayString)
        Set regExp_Matches = objRegExp_1.Execute(arrayString(i))

        If regExp_Matches.Count = 1 Then
            arrayString(i) = UCase(arrayString(i)) 'If a pattern match is found, the corresponding string is converted to uppercase and stored back
        End If
    Next

    result = Join(arrayString, " ") 'Combines elements of the modified array of words into a single string
    MsgBox (result)
End Sub
```

Comment: You have not told use what is wrong with the code and on which line the error is thrown

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code. I just want to add above conditions to my code.

Comment: @pz1 Actually you ask us to add the above conditions for you to your code? That's no free coding service. You should try to add them on your own, then show what you have tried and where your issues or errors were.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ okay, i'll add it here.

Answer (score 0):

without regex

```
Sub Main()
    Dim arrayString() As String
    longString = Range("A1").Text
    arrayString = Split(longString) 'Splits the string into an array of words so that each one can be matched with the REGEX pattern to check if its alphanumeric
    s = ""
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrayString)
      If alfaNumeric(arrayString(i)) = True Then
        p = InStr(longString, arrayString(i))
        Exit For
      Else
        s = s & arrayString(i) & " "
      End If
    Next
    If s = "" Then
      Range("B1") = longString
    Else
      Range("B1") = s
      Range("C1") = Right(longString, Len(longString) - p + 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I really appreciate for your help. However this code doesn't give me expected output. e.g I have string "length of prd is 90x90mm long". After running above code b1 cell contains word "length" and c1 has "of prd is 90x90mm long".

I'd like to have string "length of prd is" in b1 and text "90x90mm long" in C1.

If string like "90x90mm long" in a1. it shouldn't split the string because first word of the string is alphanumeric. it should paste it in b1.